# Sage plant leaves droop and die

Tags: diagnosis

My salvia was really thriving and then suddenly the leaves began to go soft, droop and die off. The other plants in the high bed seem fine and I water them all equally. It is next to some bush beans, capsicum, and chives. I thought perhaps it needed more drainage (although there is no bottom to the bed), so I elevated it. But it still continues to die back. I used regular all-purpose gardening soil in about a 1-2 foot layer, plus sand, over compost and dried wood, leaves as the bottom-most layer (about 1-2 feet). The salvia planted in other parts of the garden both in beds and the ground (sandy) seem fine. Could the soil in this bed be too rich for it?

Thankful for any clues,
M

[image: ge]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try not watering them so much...they like dry, sandy conditions. :)
Bunny

Comment: Thanks Bunny, maybe I will try not to water it as much or transplant it and see if that helps!